# JS countdown seems to be running twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running the following function on my website. It works as a basic timer and once i = 0 it should proceed to the else statement as it does. It then runs through an AJAX GET and outputs a single number to $assetID. My issue is that this seems to be running twice. I get two alerts when I should be only getting one. Any idea on what I may be doing wrong?

```
var i = 3;
function timer() {

    if (i <= 3 && i > 0) {

        $('#count').fadeIn();
        $('#count').attr('src', 'images/'+i+'.png');

        setTimeout(timer, 1000);

        i--;

    } else {

            //var intProcessingTimeout = 0;

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "index_ajax.php",
                data: "action=submit_info",
                complete: function(data){
                        //console.log(data);

                        i = 3;
                        $assetID = data.responseText.replace(/ /g,'');
                        //$assetID = $.trim($(this).text());

                        alert($assetID);


                        $('#get-ready, #count, #swf_file, #back').fadeOut('slow', function() {

                            $('#preview-poster').fadeIn();
                            $('.your_poster').fadeIn();
                            checkAssetStatusNew();

                        });


                }
          });

    }
}
```

`timer()` is being called here:

```
$(".take_photo").click(function () {


    $('#preview-page, #back').fadeOut('slow', function() {

          $('#get-ready').fadeIn();
          $('#swf_file').fadeIn();

          //setTimeout(timer, 1000); //DOESNT WORK HERE - RUNS TWICE

    });

         setTimeout(timer, 1000); // WORKS HERE FOR SOME REASON


});
```

EDIT: Moving the `setTimeout(timer, 1000);` outside of the fadeOut function seems to make it work how it should. Not sure why it would run twice when inside the fadeOut function.

Comment: Where are you calling the `timer()`?

Comment: Where are you trying the alert()?

Comment: Please make a jsFiddle or a CodePen of it. or a site with a running sample.

Comment: @ATOzTOA the alert is called after the ajax complete. I'm only doing this for testing. But the fact it alerts twice means something is going wrong. I've updated w/ when timer() is being called.

Comment: @Ladineko I can't reproduce the problem in jsFiddle. But here is a simple version of what I'm doing. http://jsfiddle.net/ywqxN/2/

Comment: In the jsFiddle, the alert() is only shown once... which browser?

Comment: @Jako: Works fine for me too, unless you click more than once, of course. You can guard against that by storing the timerID returned by `setTimeout` and checking or clearing it on subsequent clicks. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ywqxN/4/).

Comment: @Jako Works fine for me as well. Do you by any chance have another call to `timer` somewhere in your code that you're not aware of?

Comment: @troy no. the only places are when take_photo is clicked and within the timer function itself to loop.

Comment: It appears that the `fadeOut function` might be screwing things up when take_photo is clicked. Is there any reason why that would cause an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The timer block is working fine... tried logs...

```
Timer start...
If block...
Timer start...
If block...
Timer start...
If block...
Timer start...
Else block...
```

Exactly as expected.

Try replacing

```
complete: function(data){...}
```

with

```
success: function(data){...},
error: function(err){...)
```